# How do I arrange multiple arguments with string formatting in python

Tags: python

I have this piece of code and I'm trying to figure out how to have multiple arguments in that second set of brackets. I want the number to be right aligned in 6 places and rounded to 2 decimal points. I get the error 'invalid format specifier' every time.

```
print("{0:>5}   {1:>6, 6.2f}".format(pounds, euros))
```

Comment: Read the [format string documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), you'll notice that one can only specify the format width *once* and *precision* appears after the `'.'`:

```
>>> "{0:>5}   {1:>6,.2f}".format(10, 1500.657)
'   10   1,500.66'
```